# Error Message: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to grab historical temperatures at a certain time from the Wunderground API and I'm getting the following errors. Any help would be appreciated!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
              String date = "20161211";
                String sURL = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/da7962c092ba005b/history_"
                       + date + "/q/autoip.json";
              URL url = new URL(sURL);
              String temp1 = "";
              URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
              BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
              String inputLine;

              while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sURL);
                  temp1 = json.getJSONObject("observations").getString("tempi");
                  System.out.println(temp1);

          }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And I'm getting the following errors:

```
org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:432)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:184)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:310)
at Weather.main(Weather.java:54)
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you are creating a json object from your `sURL`, which is not json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a couple of things.

First of all, your json Object is getting the url, not the response.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sURL);
```

For Json you cannot parse line by line, you need to get the whole response.

The response should be something like:

```
yc.getContent()
```

When you get the input stream, you are trying to pass values to the URL, not get the results back.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to write:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(inputLine );
```

instead of:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sURL);
```

but it still won't be correct - you have to read whole String from InputStream (all lines) and only then construct JSONObject (once, not in loop).

Answer (score 0):

If you get JSONObject text must begin with '{' exception. Then first of all check what you passed to the JSONObject constructor.

You should pass the right json.txt file. So make sure what you are passing to jsonobject.

String request = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("/home/achaure/Downloads/Amol/KountRestTest/Documents/request.txt"));

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(request);